# Angular architects module federation loads in the lazy loaded module dynamically but it is not visible on the page

Tags: angular, webpack-5, angular-module-federation, angular-lazyloading

I am using Angular 2 with module federation. I have 3 apps:

1. Main (host)
2. Child1 (remote)
3. Child2 (remote)

The structure is: Child1 and Child2 are exposed and Main is taking them as remotes.
Child1 is injected to Main -> that is working fine.
BUT my problem is I want to inject Child2 inside Child1 also. (I am using dynamic method: import and compile module then show via view container ref)

I got the logs that the Child2 module is compiled -> created -> loaded properly but still it is not visible on the page of Child1. (While the same is working fine with Child2 -> Main)

I am expecting that Child2 should be visible on Child1 as well.